# RecyclerView item animation, onAnimationFinished called, but not onAnimationStarted. Why?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I assign `myRecyclerView` with `itemAnimator` as below (in Kotlin), so that I could listen to the animation start and end events.

```
    myRecyclerView.itemAnimator = object : DefaultItemAnimator() {
        override fun onAnimationFinished(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?) {
            Log.d("Testing", "I am finished")
        }
        override fun onAnimationStarted(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?) {
            Log.d("Testing", "I am started")
        }
    }
```

I use `DiffUtil` to dispatch changes. The animation works fine. But only the `onAnimationFinished` callback is getting called, not `onAnimationStarted`. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

`ItemAnimator#onAnimationStarted` and `ItemAnimator#onAnimationFinished` are called by `ItemAnimator#dispatchAnimationStarted` and `ItemAnimator#dispatchAnimationFinished` respectively.

From the doc of [`ItemAnimator#dispatchAnimationStarted`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html#dispatchAnimationStarted(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder)):

> Method to be called by subclasses when an animation is started.

After looking at the source code of `ItemAnimator`'s subclass `SimpleItemAnimator` and its subclass `DefaultItemAnimator`, I found that the `ItemAnimator#dispatchAnimationStarted` has not been called anywhere in any of the subclasses. However, `ItemAnimator#dispatchAnimationFinished` has been invoked from the subclasses.

And that is why you did not get any callback for your `onAnimationStarted` implementation.

However, I'm not sure whether this is intentionally left or a bug in the framework and I couldn't find any resources about that.